# Panoramas in Android

Tags: java, android, image, panoramas

I have been trying to filter the panorama files in order to use them. I noticed that they have the same extension as normal images ". Jpg"..

Is there a clear way to differentiate between normal images and panoramic ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use to find jpg-panoramas through the android mediaDB: panorama means (with/height > 2) or (height/widh > 2)